# YQL Forex Historical Prices Queries -- how to change default precision

Tags: yahoo, yql, finance, forex

I'm using the YQL console to retrieve historical forex prices using a query like this:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol  in ("EURUSD=X") and startDate = "2012-07-01" and endDate ="2012-07-16"
```

My problem is that the prices returned are rounded by Yahoo to 2 decimal places, which is not very useful for forex since forex quotes are usually (at least) four decimal places. For example here is a fragment of the result of that query:

```
{
     "date": "2012-07-13",
     "Date": "2012-07-13",
     "Open": "1.22",
     "High": "1.22",
     "Low": "1.22",
     "Close": "1.22",
     "Volume": "000",
     "Adj_Close": "1.22"
}
```

If you look at the EUR/USD prices on the Yahoo Finance pages, they are all four decimal places. So... what do I need to do to my query to make it return unrounded prices?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to be possible with YQL and Yahoo Finance. If you attempt the underlying query on Yahoo Finance it returns a csv with data that only has 2 decimal places.

[YQL Console Query](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22%2C%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22%29%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env#h=%0Aselect%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%20in%20%28%22EURUSD%3DX%22%29%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222012-07-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%222012-07-16%22)

Data URL: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?g=d&f=2012&e=16&c=2012&b=1&a=6&d=6&s=EURUSD%3dX

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to use YQL with the accuracy you desire since it now displays at least 4 decimals places in the results.

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "EUR=X" and startDate = "2009-09-11" and endDate = "2010-03-10"
```

The above statement will produce the following results:

```
"quote": [
    {
     "Symbol": "EUR%3dX",
     "Date": "2010-03-10",
     "Open": "0.73479",
     "High": "0.73808",
     "Low": "0.73117",
     "Close": "0.73296",
     "Volume": "000",
     "Adj_Close": "0.73296"
    },
```